# "object not found" when running lm

Tags: r

I am getting an "object not found" error when trying to run `lm`. I am not sure why but all of the data is inputted correctly: I'm Looking for any insight. I have tried altering the order of the objects but it seems always the last object is not found.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pictures are neither code nor data unless the topic is image processing. Click on the "r" below your question. Go to the "info" tab and follow the advice/links for how to create a reproducible question with data + code (and text versions of errors). Help others help you.

Comment: Use `+` to include multiple predictors in your regression, like `lm(salary ~ A + ... + BB.K)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your predictor variables need to combined with `+`, not given as a comma-separated list:

```
lm(response ~ predictor1 + predictor2 + predictor3 + ...,
      data=my_data)
```